# I am working on a Flask + ReactJs project and in my flask api getting this error: AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, sqlalchemy

Here is my flask api code. I have connected the database using sqlalchemy and created a model for the table queries.
I am working on a Flask + ReactJs project and in my flask api getting this error: AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'append'.

````
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json

with open('C:\\Users\\new\\Desktop\\ems\\api\\venv\\config.json', 'r') as c:
    params = json.load(c)["params"]

local_server = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'super-secret-key'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = params['upload_location']

if local_server:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = params['local_uri']
else:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = params['prod_uri']

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Employee(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    contact = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    designation = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)


@app.route("/employee")
def employee():
    employee_list = Employee.query.all()
    employee = []
    for employee in employee_list:
        employee.append({'id' : employee.id,
                        'name' : employee.name,
                        'email' : employee.email,
                        'contact' : employee.contact,
                        'designation' : employee.designation})
    return jsonify({'employee' : employee})


@app.route("/add", methods=['POST'])
def add():
    employee_data = request.get_json()
    new_employee = Employee(id = employee_data['id'],
                            name = employee_data['name'],
                            email = employee_data['email'],
                            contact = employee_data['contact'],
                            designation = employee_data['designation'])
    db.session.add(new_employee)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'Added Successfully', 201


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)```
````

Comment: You are attempting to run `employee.append` though such a function doesn't exist and isn't defined. You need to create the function and make it do something prior to calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three objects with the same name (this is not good practice as it confuses you and ends up introducing bugs like the one you just encountered):

- employee (1): the function for the flask route
- employee (2): the empty list you are trying to append to
- employee (3): the name of the current element in the for loop

Every time you create a new variable with the same name in the same namespace, the older variable is overwritten. In your case the function `employee()` faces no problem. But the two variables `employee = []` and `for employee in employee_list:` end up clashing, and python ends up deleting the `employee = []` and now `employee` is pointing to the item in loop, which doesn't have an `append` method since its an object from the class `Employee`.

To solve the problem change the name of your list or the name of the loop variable.

```py
@app.route("/employee")
def employee():
    employee_list = Employee.query.all()
    employees = [] # <--- changed from `employee` to `employees`
    for employee in employee_list:
        employee.append({'id' : employee.id,
                        'name' : employee.name,
                        'email' : employee.email,
                        'contact' : employee.contact,
                        'designation' : employee.designation})
    return jsonify({'employee' : employee}) # <--- changed from `employee` to `employees`
```